# How can i change my system's IP through R?

Tags: r

I want to change my system's ip through R , is there any way this can be done ? 
have tried below answer by Pablo Barbera but couldn't actually worked .

```
library(RCurl)
# check current IP address
print(getURL("http://ifconfig.me/ip"))
# proxy options
opts <- list(proxy="127.0.0.1", proxyport=8118)
# opening connection with TOR
con <- socketConnection(host="127.0.0.1",port=9051)
print(getURL("http://ifconfig.me/ip", .opts = opts))  

for (i in 1:10)
    {
    writeLines('AUTHENTICATE \"password\"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n', con=con)
    Sys.sleep(5)
    print(getURL("http://ifconfig.me/ip", .opts = opts)) 
    Sys.sleep(5)
    }
```

LINK : [Changing Tor identity in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089993/changing-tor-identity-in-r)

Can anybody make me understand what this code is saying and how this is wroking ?